# What is the most effective way to sort dataframe and add special id?

Tags: r, sorting

I have a very very big dataset and I am looking for the fastest and most effective way to sort and give an id to a dataframe based on values in two columns. I have a dataframe where column `"value 1"` has unique values while column `"value 2"` has not. column `"absdiff"` gives the difference between these two columns. I want to add `ID` in the dataframe as first column which gives the closest distance to the respective "group/value" in the column `"value2"`. So, exemplatory this is what I have:

```
data <- data.frame(value1 = c(5,5.1,5.2,4.9,8.2,8.0,13,13.3,18), 
                   value2 = c(5,5,5,5,8,8,13,13,18))
data$absdiff <- with(data, c(abs(data$value1 - data$value2)))

  value1 value2 absdiff
  5.00      5    0.00
  5.10      5    0.10
  5.20      5    0.20
  4.89      5    0.11
  8.20      8    0.20
  8.00      8    0.00
 13.00     13    0.00
 13.30     13    0.30
 18.00     18    0.00
```

and what I want to have is (note the slight different order as `ID` is sorted):

```
ID  value1 value2 absdiff
1   5.00      5    0.00
2   5.10      5    0.10
3   4.89      5    0.11
4   5.20      5    0.20
1   8.00      8    0.00
2   8.20      8    0.20
1  13.00     13    0.00
2  13.30     13    0.30
1  18.00     18    0.00
```

I know there is plyr, apply etc. But what is the most effective way, are there others? The dataset I have is in GB range so it makes a difference.

Comment: Is this just a counter from 1:n within each group? If so, I'm near certain this has been asked before here.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate:  but anyway, the solution sounds like `library(dplyr) new.df <- data %>%
  group_by(value2) %>%
  arrange(absdiff) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())`

Comment: many thanks for this solution but my main concern is the speed of evaluation of all possible ways to create this kind of "counter". If anybody has experience with this and comparison of calculation speed between eg. plyr and apply etc.

Comment: Use `microbenchmark` to do your own quick comparison of speed?

Comment: Okay thanks, I will check this, any other solutions in mind despite plyr I could use for speed comparison?

Comment: Looks like a use case for `rank()`. And, for large data sets, I recommend `data.table` with its fast rank function: `library(data.table); setDT(data)[, ID := frank(absdiff, ties.method = "first"), by = value2][order(value2, ID)]`.